# Does the Apple podcasts app differ by ios version or iphone version?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, podcasts, podcasts.app

I'm using the Apple podcasts app on ios 14.6 on an iphone 7+ and on the Library tab there is a "Recently updated" section, but my friend has an iphone XR on ios 14.6 and on his Library tab it says "Recently followed". Does the app differ based on iphone version instead of ios version?

Comment: All Apple apps are subject to changes large and small any time Apple updates the OS. Small changes happen all the time, larger visible changes happen (usually) on version upgrades, EG iOS 11 to iOS 12.